# Calculate the probability that $X+Y\leq 1$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The random variable $X,Y$ have joint density function $$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix} 3(2-x)y,& \mbox{if} \, 0<y<1\,\mbox{and}\, y<x<2-y\\
0,& \mbox{otherwise.}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Calculate the probability that $X+Y\leq 1$.

I'm struggling to determine the upper bound of the outer integral. I have $$P(X+Y\leq 1)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{1-y}f(x,y)dxdy.$$ I thought the bounds of the outer integral must be deterministic (i.e. numbers and not variables). I have the bounds 0 and 1 for $y$ from the density function. I determined that the upper bound of $x$ is $1-y$ since $x+y\leq 1 \implies x\leq 1-y$; lower bound of $x$ is determined by the density function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the calculation is the easy part. The hard part is to mentally conceive that the bound can be a variable. This is why, personally, if I had to tutor a student, I would recommend him to draw a graph.

Answer (score 1):

The upper bound must be greater than $y$ in the integral in $x$ since $x>y$... So you need $\max(y,1-y)$ as upper bound...

This means that for $y\in[1/2,1)$, where the max is $y$, the integral is $0$. So you can rewrite $\int_0^{1/2}$ for $y$ and let $\int_y^{1-y}$ for $x$.

$$P(X+Y\leq 1)=\int_{0}^{1/2}\int_{y}^{1-y}f(x,y)dxdy = 9\int_0^{1/2}\left(\frac{y}{2}-y^2\right)dy =\frac{3}{16}\,.$$

Comment: Thank you for this! I drew a graph and I see that there are two regions as you said, one for $y\in [\frac{1}{2}, 1) $ and another for $y\in (1,\frac{1}{2})$. @ECL

Answer (score 0):

What happens if we have two independent random variables A and B, where the distribution for A is: $f(a)=a$ for $0\leq a\leq1$ and 0 otherwise, and the distribution for B is $f(b)=\frac{2-b}{2}$ for $0\leq a\leq2$?

Our probability distribution is the same as this one, except with the condition that out result for b is somewhere in the range that $A<B<2-A$.

Therefore $P(X+Y\leq1)=P(A+B\leq1|A<B<2-A)=\frac{
P(A+B\leq1\cap A<B<2-A)}{P(A<B<2-A)}=\frac{P(A<B\leq1-A)}{P(A<B<2-A)}$

$$P(A<B\leq1-A)= \int_0^\frac{1}{2}\int_a^{1-a}(a\frac{2-b}{2}) dbda =\int_{0}^\frac{1}{2}a\int_a^{1-a}(1-\frac{b}{2})dbda =\int_0^\frac{1}{2}a((1-2a)+\frac{a^2}{4}-\frac{a^2-2a+1}{4})da =\int_0^\frac{1}{2}a((1-2a)+\frac{2a-1}{4})da =\frac{1}{4}\int_0^\frac{1}{2}4a-8a^2+2a^2-a da=\frac{3}{4}\int_0^\frac{1}{2}a-2a^2da= \frac{3}{4}(\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{12})=\frac{1}{32}$$
$$P(A<B<2-A)=\int_0^1 a\int_a^{2-a}(1-\frac{b}{2})dbda=\int_0^1 2a -2a^2-\frac{a}{2}\int_a^{2-a}bdbda=\int_0^1 2a -2a^2-\frac{a}{4}(4-4a)da=\int_0^1 2a -2a^2 -a(1-a) da =\int_0^1 a-a^2 da=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{6}$$
$$\frac{\frac{1}{32}}{\frac{1}{6}}=\frac{3}{16}$$

Comment: Fixed an arithmetic error in the integral for the denominator